# How to filter queryset based on value of another model in Django?

Tags: django, search, filter, django-queryset

I'm trying to make a simple search function. I'm using the `User` model and a `UserProfile` model with a OneToOne relationship. I've successfully managed to search by the username, first name and last name, all three field being in the `User` model. However, I want to filter by the fields present in `UserProfile` model, e.g. sex, age, location, etc.

**views.py**

```
def Home(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query', '')
    queryset = User.objects.none()
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            if query != '':
                queryset = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query)
                                             | Q(first_name__icontains=query)
                                             | Q(last_name__icontains=query)).exclude(is_staff=True)
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, "main/home.html", {'form': form, 'queryset': queryset})
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <p>
    <form method="get" action="">
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    </p>

    <p>
    {% for user in queryset %}
        <a href="{% url 'main:profile' user.id %}">{{ user.get_full_name }}</a> <br/>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search...'}), required=False)
    age_from = forms.IntegerField(label="", widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Age from'}), required=False)
    age_to = forms.IntegerField(label="", widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Age to'}), required=False)
```

**models.py**

```
UserProfile(models.Model):
    sex_choices = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=6,
                           choices=sex_choices,
                           default='Male')
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

How can I include options to search based on other fields on `UserProfile` model which has a OneToOne relation with `User` model?

Comment: I think you shuld post your models.

Comment: @Gocht Added model as well as forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the related name.

As you haven't shared your models definition, let's suppose:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    sex = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

So, when you query:

```
User.objects.filter(user_profile_set__sex='female')
```

**EDIT**

To query based in age, given that you ask for an 'age' in your form and you store a birthdate in your model, you could try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
age = 18  # this shoudl come from form
birth_year = datetime.now().year - age
User.objects.filter(user_profile_set__birth_date__year=birth_year)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have added the forms.py and shortened models.py. Can you please tell me what is the best way to query the age?

Comment: In your form yo ask for an age, but in your model you have a birth day, you will need to calculate age from birth day or add an age field in your model.

Comment: If I add an age field, it will not increase by 1 per year. So I used birth_date. I think it is better to calculate age from birth_date.

Comment: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'unicode'` I tried using int() to convert to integer or u' to convert to unicode. It doesn't work. When I recreate it in python shell `User.objects.filter(user_profile_set__birth_date__year=birth_year)` <- this works but `User.objects.filter(user_profile_set__birth_date__year__gte=birth_year)` <- this doesn't work saying `Unsupported lookup 'year_gte' for DateField or join on the field not permitted.`

Comment: The traceback is highlighting this line `birth_year = datetime.now().year - age`

Comment: Please, use some online service to chare the complete traceback, I don't think that line is throwing the exception.

Comment: `age_from` is a unicode in your code my friend, convert it to `int` -> `int(age_from)`

Comment: I could've sworn I'd tried converting that to int(). Thanks man. LoL.

Comment: Also, can u please tell me about this `Unsupported lookup 'year_gte' for DateField or join on the field not permitted.` whenever I try to use `__gte` or `__lte` in my query? Traceback: http://dpaste.com/0MV1D7X

Comment: Ok wait, if I convert the age to string and write it in the date format it computes without error. I just have to figure out how to do it efficiently. Don't bother with it. :)

Comment: @MiniGunnR Looks like it is not possible, (unless not in a easy way) but you could tray something like this `User.objects.filter(user_profile_set__birth_day__gte=date(age_from, 1, 1))`

Comment: This works `filter(profile__birth_date__lte = str(birth_year_from) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day))`. Changed the related name to `profile` btw.

Comment: You've found your equation. Glad to help